# Cannot Edit Document from Office Client Some Necessary HTTP Headers are not sent by the server

Tags: document-library, check-out, office, check-in

I have a problem, where if I open a document from SharePoint Document Library, I couldn't edit it locally, the file requires to be saved locally. I cannot Checkout/Checkin, cannot edit it. It just says "[Read-Only]". Note that permission and settings has been checked properly.

Monitoring the traffic between my computer and the SharePoint server, I noticed that I am missing some HTTP Headers that are needed for Office Client to be able to do document editing.

I am missing the following HTTP Headers from the server:

- X-MSFSSHTTP
- X-MS-InvokeApp
- MS-Author-Via

So subsequently, the Office Client will not use the document editing mechanism, instead it is downloading the document for local copy.

I have read the following article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd906383(v=office.12).aspx but at step #9 the server is not sending these HTTP Headers. What could possibly go wrong? Is it a client problem? I tried to checkout the document from another <del>network</del> region with success result, so I don't think it is a server related problem, however I am stuck in where to start troubleshooting this problem.

Could someone points a direction to me where to start looking into this problem more thoroughly?

Thanks

Edit: some additional info

SP: 2013
Office: 2016
IE: 11

Comment: Your SharePoint version? Your Office version? Your browser?

Comment: Wild guess: Could you try to disable modern authentication on the client? Maybe Office will behave differently if you do so: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/modern-authentication-on-outlook-2016-keeps-on/98a263f4-ab9c-4d6f-b5eb-2728a8e77412?auth=1

Comment: Have you set firewall? This is inside company (Intranet) or Extranet problem?

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška this is internal network, firewall should not be an issue, as ports used are 80 and 443 only, but CMIIW. thanks